# update airflow variable using Variable.set()

Tags: python, json, airflow

I would like to update my value for key `something` in my nested airflow variable. Normally it is just `Variable.set(key,new_value)` but how do you do if it is nested?

```
{
  "vars": {
    "task1_args": "Task 1"
    "something": "Task something"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data is a JSON object, you can do

```py
data["vars"]["something"] = "something else"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as usual - read variable, set the key, write variable:

Something like:

```
Variable.set('variable',Variable.get('variable')['key']='value')
```

Comment: it gives an error that cannot assign function to call